# training material for WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm planning on taking the WSO2 EI developer certification and am looking for recommendation on training material for the platform (ideally version 6.4). I find the material available at their website rather confusing - there's a lot of do this or do that but little explanation on when to choose one possibility or another. I've already gone through WSO2 Developer's Guide by Estrada & Lázaro but still would like to check other sources. Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you refer [1]? This contains some of the materials that is useful. You can also follow the webinars on [2]

[1]-https://wso2.com/training/certification/certified-enterprise-integrator6-developer

[2]-https://wso2.com/library/integration/